# NVidia on startup breaks all drivers and the system

Tags: windows-7, boot, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

Based in friends advice, I've installed Nvidia driver on my system. Instead of improving performance, driver hooked into system startup and breaks the system. What happens:

1. Any external (plug'n'play) hardware is disabled - drivers are stopped.
2. Some internal hardware, like battery or network card stoppes working as well
3. In shutdown menu, all fields except "Log off" and "Switch user" are disabled

If I'm fast enough and I shut all "nvidia..." processes, system works normally. So the question is:

**How to disable Nvidia processes starting with the system?**

I didn't find them in:

- `Start Menu > On startup` folder
- `System configuration (msconfig) > On startup` tab

Driver source:
http://us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/314.07/314.07-notebook-win8-win7-winvista-64bit-international-whql.exe

Comment: There are 2 close votes and the question is in the close queue citing a statement that the problem can no longer be replicated.  I don't see any such statement, although it's likely true for a 3 yr old problem.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to roll back to a previous driver version available sometimes from Nvidia or other sites like Guru3d.com. 
If that doesn't work i suggest you that you go to a computer service store and 
if your guaranty is still available to replace it.

Comment: Well, do you imply Nvidia has destroyed my PC (as of software)? I tried restoration point with no effect.

Comment: I'm just trying to say that 'your downloaded drivers' may not be compatible with your system for some reasons if not maybe it's your graphic card that may have some issues.